# data source revealed by one radio button not correctly updating based on drop down list change

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have to radio buttons that reveal or hide panels.

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        newPanel.Visible = true;
        updatePanel.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        newPanel.Visible = false;
        updatePanel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Outside of these panels is a drop down list which effects a data source (gridview). The second radio button reveals the panel that holds this data source. The code for changing that happens when a different item selected from the drop down menu is as follows:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //change WHERE clause for SQL statement that effects grid view based on drop down menu selection
    SqlDataSource4.SelectParameters["userIdSelected"].DefaultValue = userNameDropDown.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

This functions correctly and updates changes the data source that is being displayed.

However, if I currently have the first radio button chosen (that reveals a different panel) and then change the name from the drop down list, when I go to the second radio button the panel that opens shows the data source that was previous. It does not correctly reflect the change to the drop down menu.

Edit: I have tried adding the change to the radio button change but I still have the same behavior:

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource4.SelectParameters["userIdSelected"].DefaultValue = userNameDropDown.SelectedItem.Value;

    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        newPanel.Visible = true;
        updatePanel.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        newPanel.Visible = false;
        updatePanel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trigering DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged in any way

Comment: DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged is triggered when the user changes the selection from the drop down menu.

Comment: based on your question you want it to change when radiobutton changes

Comment: I tried that, by adding SqlDataSource4.SelectParameters["userIdSelected"].DefaultValue = userNameDropDown.SelectedItem.Value; under RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged() but the behavior remains the same.